# liferay problems for connecting to postgres

Tags: liferay, portal

I want to connect liferay ce to postgres so I have added portal-ext.properties to the following path

```
${CATALINA_HOME}/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes
```

with this context

```
jdbc.default.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
jdbc.default.url=jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/postgres
jdbc.default.username=postgres
jdbc.default.password=postgres
```

I Should mentioned that I put postgres.jar in `${CATALINA_HOME}/lib/ext`
but when I run tomcat I face with following errors:

```
11:39:13,261 WARN  [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#8][BasicResourcePool:1841] com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@f274b4 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (3). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:279)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.driver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:223)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:134)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:148)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
11:39:13,274 ERROR [pool-2-thread-1][ContextLoader:227] Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.liferay.portal.spring.aop.ServiceBeanAutoProxyCreator#0' defined in class path resource [META-INF/base-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'serviceAdvice' while setting bean property 'methodInterceptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceAdvice' defined in class path resource [META-INF/base-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'asyncAdvice' while setting bean property 'nextMethodInterceptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'asyncAdvice' defined in class path resource [META-INF/base-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'threadLocalCacheAdvice' while setting bean property 'nextMethodInterceptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'threadLocalCacheAdvice' defined in class path resource [META-INF/base-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'bufferedIncrementAdvice' while setting bean property 'nextMethodInterceptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bufferedIncrementAdvice' defined in class path resource [META-INF/base-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'indexableAdvice' while setting bean property 'nextMethodInterceptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'indexableAdvice' defined in class path resource [META-INF/base-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionAdvice' while setting bean property 'nextMethodInterceptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionAdvice' defined in class path resource [META-INF/base-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'liferayTransactionManager' while setting bean property 'platformTransactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liferayTransactionManager' defined in class path resource [META-INF/hibernate-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'liferayHibernateSessionFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liferayHibernateSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [META-INF/hibernate-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1327)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1085)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:710)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at com.liferay.portal.spring.context.PortalContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(PortalContextLoaderListener.java:172)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:895)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:649)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1585)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceAdvice' defined in class path resource [META-INF/base-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'asyncAdvice' while setting bean property 'nextMethodInterceptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'asyncAdvice' defined in class path resource [META-INF/base-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'threadLocalCacheAdvice' while setting bean property 'nextMethodInterceptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'threadLocalCacheAdvice' defined in class path resource [META-INF/base-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'bufferedIncrementAdvice' while setting bean property 'nextMethodInterceptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'bufferedIncrementAdvice' defined in class path resource [META-INF/base-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'indexableAdvice' while setting bean property 'nextMethodInterceptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'indexableAdvice' defined in class path resource [META-INF/base-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'transactionAdvice' while setting bean property 'nextMethodInterceptor'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionAdvice' defined in class path resource [META-INF/base-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'liferayTransactionManager' while setting bean property 'platformTransactionManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liferayTransactionManager' defined in class path resource [META-INF/hibernate-spring.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'liferayHibernateSessionFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liferayHibernateSessionFactory' defined in class path resource [META-INF/hibernate-spring.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1327)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1085)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 29 more
```

what should I do?`
thanks for your suggestions

Comment: "*java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver*" means the driver was not found. Try putting the driver jar file into `lib/ext` instead of `lib`

Answer (score 2):

java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

Put **"postgresql"** jar into **tomcat/lib/ext** folder

HTH